# isset and != in the same if clause

Tags: php

In my script a particular array element (say, `$foo['bar']`) can take different values, or no value at all. A particular action is triggered if the value of `$foo['bar']` is **not equal** to, say, 42. The following code

```
if (!isset($foo['bar']) || ($foo['bar'] != '42')) action()
```

is not ideal, because php issues a warning about when `$foo['bar']` is not set.

Question: is there an elegant way to test for such condition?

Comment: The warning appears in `($foo['bar'] != '42')`. `$foo['bar']` is not set, so the comparison is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
if (!isset($foo['bar']) || $foo['bar'] != 42) {
}
```

Because of short-circuiting logic will actually **not issue any warnings**, because it skips at the first truthy condition, in this case that happens if `$foo['bar']` is not defined.

This can also be seen from the opcodes that the compiler generates for your code:

```
compiled vars:  !0 = $foo
line  # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3  0  >   ZEND_ISSET_ISEMPTY_DIM_OBJ                    1  ~0      !0, 'bar'
      1      BOOL_NOT                                         ~1      ~0
      2    > JMPNZ_EX                                         ~1      ~1, ->6
      3  >   FETCH_DIM_R                                      $2      !0, 'bar'
      4      IS_NOT_EQUAL                                     ~3      $2, 42
      5      BOOL                                             ~1      ~3
      6  > > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->8
   4  7  > > JMP                                                      ->8
      8  > > RETURN                                                   1
```

The below opcode is important:

```
2    > JMPNZ_EX                                         ~1      ~1, ->6
```

The inverted outcome of `isset($foo['bar'])` gets checked and if truthy the code jumps over the next few statements that actually inspect the value of `$foo['bar']`, thereby avoiding any notices.

This also means that if you would reverse the two operands of `||` you *will* get a notice and the second operand is mostly useless anyway.

Because values like `0`, `false`, `[]`, etc. are also not equal to `42` you can use `empty()` as well:

```
if (empty($foo['bar']) || $foo['bar'] != 42) {
}
```

This arguably makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @VitalieCiubotaru Yeah, you would get a notice if you reverse the operands.

Comment: @EmilioGort codepad.viper-7.com has an option for it; there's also a pecl package for it, should be as simple as `pecl install vld`.

Answer (score 2):

Can be in this way

```
$bar = isset($foo['bar']) ? $foo['bar'] : NULL;
```

There you don't get warning and you are setting the variable.

Then you do the check

```
 if($bar != 42 && !empty($bar)){
    //do something
 }
```

Read [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to `expr2` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` if `expr1` evaluates to `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I ended up with. This approach takes an extra variable, so I was thinking of some one-line magic with the conditional statements...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
if (!(isset($foo['bar']) && ($foo['bar'] = '42'))) action();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This line looks beautiful. I'll give it a run to see if it doesn't throw the warning/notice.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.3+ you can use optimitzed version of [Emilio Gort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726005/emilio-gort) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129528/2648942):

```
$bar = isset($foo['bar']) ?: '';
if ($bar != 42) action();
```